# copy does not work in gnome-shell

Tags: gnome-terminal, copy, gnome-shell, paste

I just upgrade my computer from ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10, the copy(keyboard shortcut ctrl+shift+c or copy from popover menu) in gnome-shell sometimes works, sometimes doesn't, all my software was update to the newest, and gnome version is 3.26.1.

I am not sure is there any other information i can provide, if there is, please tell me and I will reply as soon as possible.

Any help will be greatly appreciated~

Comment: You have to copy paste from the menu or highlight text and right mouse click.

Comment: thank you~ I tried in this way,  maybe my expression is not so clear,  i just edit it again

Comment: Does it work if you run 17.10 from a live usb ?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/971402/why-cant-i-copy-text-from-terminal-after-17-10-upgrade.

Comment: @egmont thank you, it really helps,  i can use ctrl+shift+t to avoid this bug for now

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers: Ctrl+Shift+T is gnome-termial's shortcut for opening a new tab (if the focus is at an existing gnome-terminal window), whereas Ctrl+Alt+T is usually the global shortcut to open a new terminal (no matter which app is focused). Perhaps you meant the letter, not sure, really doesn't matter. I myself keep mixing up these two all the time :-)